# カメラロールに保存した画像のフルパスを取得したい

Tags: xcode, swift5, xcode12

以下のコードは、動画を選択し、一画面を静止画にしてカメラロールに保存するコードです。
保存した画像のフルパスを取得したいです
リンクに同じような内容があったので参考にさせてもらいましたが、スコープ内に見つかりません等のエラーが出ます。

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Photos

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    var picker = UIImagePickerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // フォトライブラリーから動画を取得
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
        picker.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
        picker.delegate = self
        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]){
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        guard let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL else {
            return
        }
        let asset = AVAsset(url: videoURL)
        let generator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        // 1秒毎にUIImageを生成

            let floatTime = Float64(1)
            let time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(floatTime, preferredTimescale: 10)
            let image = try? generator.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)

        //タップイベントを追加
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: self.view.frame)
        imageView.image = UIImage(cgImage:image!)
        print(asset.duration)

        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.saveImage(_:))))


        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: view.frame.width - 20, height: (view.frame.width-20)*3/4)

        self.view.addSubview(imageView)


    }

    @objc func saveImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

            //タップしたUIImageViewを取得
            let targetImageView = sender.view! as! UIImageView
            // その中の UIImage を取得
            let targetImage = targetImageView.image!
            //保存するか否かのアラート
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "保存", message: "この画像を保存しますか？", preferredStyle: .alert)
            //OK
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (ok) in
                //ここでフォトライブラリに画像を保存　(ここでパス取得？)
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(targetImage, self, #selector(self.showResultOfSaveImage(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
            }
            //CANCEL
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "CANCEL", style: .default) { (cancel) in
                alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            //OKとCANCELを表示追加し、アラートを表示
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
            alertController.addAction(okAction)
            present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
     // 保存結果をアラートで表示
    @objc func showResultOfSaveImage(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError!, contextInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) {

            var title = "保存完了"
            var message = "カメラロールに保存しました"

            if error != nil {
                title = "エラー"
                message = "保存に失敗しました"
            }

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

            // OKボタンを追加
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))

            // UIAlertController を表示
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

}
```

参考にしたサイト

https://stackoverrun.com/ja/q/12649411

Comment: 参照されたページは StackOverflow のコンテンツを (無断で) 機械翻訳したサイトです。ソースとなるページは https://stackoverflow.com/q/46110993

Comment: 関係ないですけどStack OverflowのコンテンツはCC-BY-SAなので翻訳に許可はいらないんじゃないでしょうか。

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi ライセンス的には確かに問題ないのかもしれませんが、メタにて関連する話題がいくつか挙がっていますので参考にしてください。https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2905 , https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3118

Comment: これらの議論については理解しています。またこのようなサイトが現状において益よりも害の方が大きいというのも同意できます。ただ翻訳に許可が不要ということとはまったく別の話で「無断で」というのは個々の感情の問題にすぎないので切り分けるべきと思います。オリジナルの参照を示すことは良いと思います。